# Does Eclipse Link work together with Vertica

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, vertica

i'm currently testing vertica. Since vertica has a jdbc driver it should be possible to get it working.

Is there a simple way to get Eclipse link to support vertica?
Are there alternative orm framework (like hibernate) that support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Vertica Support Hibernate queries works with the `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` while this is true there are still some problems (exspecially with hbm2ddl) that can only be fixed with a custom dialect.

Among those are:

- data type mapping: there are no 4 byte datatypes, so the default java int mapping to int4 doesn't work. same goes for several other types.
- no indexes: for obvious reasons vertica doesn't know create index, if your model contains @index annotations, remove them

not sure how far postgres is from vertica but with my own custom dialect that inherits the postgres dialect everything works so far.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a compliant JDBC driver EclipseLink should work with Vertica.

Some features such as DDL generation, may require a custom DatabasePlatform class, which you could create if required.  Most features should work with the generic DatabasePlatform.

Are you encountering any specific issues?

Comment: so you say that "using" the database (f.e. insert, select,...) should work? so far we didn't get past the schema generation stage. i will try this tomorrow.

Comment: If Vertica is similar to Postgres, then set your target-database to postgresql

Answer (score 0):

We recently tried to get Hibernate working with vertica unsuccessfully. One of the problems was an inexistent dialect for that combination.
After consulting a Vertica consultant the answer was that there is no plans to provide this sort of support as ORMs like hibernate and a DB like Vertica provide different approaches for data storage.

Comment: according to the vertica knowledge base they support hibernate. well, i wrote a mail to the support. hope they can help.

Comment: got an answer from vertica. hibernate works when you use the posgres dialect `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect` tested it successfully